# How to handle a custom alert box in robot framework scripts?

Tags: alert

I am writing automated tests in Robot Framework using the selenium library.
There is a browser pop up that appears like in the attached image. Since the pop up is not an html element, I am unable to use the "Click Element" keyword to click the "Open Microsoft Store" button or "Always allow....." check box (this is not what I am working on).[Screenshot of the alert box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0VuR.png)

I have tried using the Handle Alert, Alert Should Be Present, but none of them seem to work. How do I best approach this? When I use the "Execute JavaScript" keyword to invoke the alert box, the Handle Alert works perfectly but doesn't work on the alert which is shown in the image attached.

I have tried to also use the Press Keys with the left arrow key to bring the focus to the "Open Microsoft Store", and using the Press Keys with enter but nothing is working.

```
*** Settings ***
```

Library     SeleniumLibrary

Test Teardown       Close Browser

*** Test Cases ***

Lenovo Tests
[Tags]          lenovo

```
Open Browser        https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/lenovo-vantage/9WZDNCRFJ4MV?hl=en-us&gl=us            chrome
Maximize Browser Window

Sleep    2
Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath://button[@id="getOrRemoveButton-9WZDNCRFJ4MV"]                            10
Click Element                       xpath://button[@id="getOrRemoveButton-9WZDNCRFJ4MV"]
Sleep    2

Alert Should Be Present    action=ACCEPT    timeout=10
#Handle Alert        action=DISMISS      timeout=10

Capture Page Screenshot
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.